# How to enable javaScript in web browser control in windows form in c#?

Tags: asp.net, web, webbrowser-control

I have application in `asp.net`. I want to open it in web browser control in window form. I run it by just giving the url in the properties of browser. It successfully runs. But my javascrpit file does not work.

Can anybody help me in this regarding how javascript will work?

Thanks

Comment: What is does not work?  you get an error?  its just never called?  details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebBrowser control doesn't have such property to set to enable or disable javascript. If you want to enable/disable javascript, you can enable/disable it in your Internet Security option in the Windows system. That option can be found as below:
Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3264223f-d5c0-4c1a-b550-3621ca17635f/

Best regards.