# Visual Studio web browser control not running Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2015 and have encountered a problem. I'm creating a small Windows Forms Application program which uses the web browser tool. When it launches, it goes to a webpage which uses Javascript and doesn't launch these scripts. I don't know how to activate Javascript on the web browser control. IE works fine for me. I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit. Here is the code:
**EDIT: I have already enabled javascript on IE since that website works perfectly when I use IE to access it.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("www.webpage.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that in WebBrowser control. This has to be done in ur IE settings.

Comment: What are the chances that javascript isn't loading in your IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable javaScript in web browser control in windows form in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040216/how-to-enable-javascript-in-web-browser-control-in-windows-form-in-c)

Comment: where is your javascript? html page?